# Python How to calculate percentage of a text found in every row

Tags: python, percentage

I have a CVS with one column and 4000 rows i want to make a script that can print each unique word and its percentage that is on that CSV

Example:

```
Trojan
Trojan
redirects
Exploits
Trojan
```

Trojan: 60%
Redirects: 20%
Exploits 20%

What is the easy/simple way to do this?

[here is a image with the data i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEYRc.png)

```
import csv
myDict = {}

with open('export.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for word in csvfile:
        if word in myDict:
            myDict[word] += 1
        else:
            myDict[word] = 1

for word in myDict:
    print word, float(myDict[word])/len(csvfile)
```

Comment: I want a good grade and a job without having to work.

Comment: im not asking for you guys to do this just hint or help what to use to make this. i didnt found much about this on google and i want to know what to use can difflib do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary as below:

```
import csv

myDict = {}
row_number = 0

with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        row_number +=1
        if row[0] in myDict:
            myDict[row[0]] += 1
        else:
            myDict[row[0]] = 1

for word in myDict:
    print word, float(myDict[word])/row_number
```

Works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Trojan 0.6
Exploits 0.2
redirects 0.2
>>>
```

Comment: This seems what i needed thanks alot! can this work importing a csv file? i have updated the question but dont seem to work.

Comment: still cant make it work, now im getting error word is not defined but it is here "for word in myDict:" right?

Comment: @JohnPDC Accidentally I deleted myDict variable after edition. New updated answer seems okay. I added it again.

Comment: ye noticed you forgot it but again i get  "namerror: name 'word' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You can use set to get all unique values and count to get the number of occurrences. Dividing by the length of the list with text yields the percentage:

```
text = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
[(i, text.count(i) * 100. / len(text)) for i in set(text)]
```

resulting in:

```
[('a', 50.0), ('b', 25.0), ('c', 25.0)]
```

Comment: or just use `set()` without using any extra dependency `[(i, text.count(i) * 100. / len(text)) for i in set(text)]`

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov Thanks. Learning every day :)